# Auto fill out google form based on Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm planning to create google form wherein it will be sent quarterly to employees. Once I get their responses, I want those responses to be auto filled out when they receive again that google form on the next following quarters.

Is there a way in Google form and Google Apps Script wherein answers are automatically filled out based on previous answers that's stored in Spreadsheet? It's like rollforward of answers.

Please let me know if it's feasible.

Comment: When you say "answers are automatically filled out" you mean you want the users to receive the form with the questions answered already and then they can edit those answers if they want? If it's not the case please explain more in depth. You can edit a form based on previous answers, the problem is it's the same form for all the users, so you can't have specific pre-filled answers for each user.

Answer (score 0):

Google Forms have only one state. This is the current state.

You should avoid such complex dependent actions when you use this application.

You can create your own form. But this cannot be an answer on this forum.